# Match between open and close brackets if not empty?

Tags: regex, string

Using a regular expression, given the following text how can I match the contents between the square brackets but only if not empty?

```
{
  "key": [  
   ],

   "match": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
   ]
}
```

`/:\s*\[([^\]\[]+)\]/g`: This is my attempt, and while it matches anything within the brackets including whitespace (desired) I can't work out how to only match between brackets that are essentially an empty array (i.e.) not just whitespace.

In the text above I want to match the contents of the second key but not the whitespace of the first key.

It's important that I capture the white space as well as I want to preserve the formatting but I don't want to capture the contents between the brackets if there is none or is only whitespace/newlines etc.

You can see and play with my regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/iN9cD5/3

THANKS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage a negative lookahead:

```
:\s*\[(?!\s*])([^\]\[]+)\]
       ^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE0jM5/1)

The `(?!\s*])` will fail a match if there are just whitespace symbols or nothing after `[` before the next `]`.

In PCRE regex flavor, you can get rid of some redundant escaping symbols and use

```
:\s*\[(?!\s*])([^][]+)]`
```

See another [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE0jM5/2). The `[^][]` matches any character but `[` and `]` due to smart placing of `]` right after the character class opening `[` and `[` does not have to be escaped in a PCRE regex character class.

Comment: Perfect, I knew it had to be something like a look ahead just could not wrap my head around the syntax! Thanks so much!

Comment: BTW, the regex flavor is PHP, you can get rid of some escaping symbols: [`:\s*\[(?!\s*])([^][]+)]`](https://regex101.com/r/bE0jM5/2).

Comment: Great, the flavour I'm using is PCRE so that will make it slightly easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pattern:

```
/:\s*\[(\s+\S[^\]\[]+)\]/g
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/iN9cD5/4)

It adds in a check that multiple spaces are followed by a non-space character.